# Angular routing on apache is returning internal server error

Tags: angular, apache

I'm using the PathLocationStrategy and deployed my angular application on apache. My angular application files are inside the folder "teste", which is inside the folder "public_html". I have changed the .htaccess file that is inside the "public_html" and I'm still getting the internal server error when I reload the page:
"Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. ..."

This is my .htaccess:

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Defina o pacote ~@~\ea-php73~@~] como a linguagem padrão de programação 
~@~\PHP~@~].
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

  RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there anything else to do?

Comment: How does your <base href="" /> tag in index.html look like?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors/text when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @ZamAbdulVahid <base href="./" />

Comment: @OlafKock I have edited the question replacing the images. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are deploying the angular application into a subfolder of your root hosting folder i.e. public_hmtl, first build the app with the following command.

```
ng build --prod --base-href=/teste/
```

This will set the app base as below in index.html when the build is performed.

```
<base href="/teste/">
```

Now define the subfolder in RewriteRule of your htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /teste/index.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanksss a lot!! You've really helped me!!